# Window function in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the column 'Desired Result' from the data presented. I'm not sure of the correct syntax for the windows function to do this. I've tried row_number and versions of RANK but just can seem to get it correct. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
ID  TransactionID   Desired Result
33  2681998458900   1
44  2682232081872   1
44  2682232081872   1
44  2682232081872   1
44  2683269923140   2
44  2683269923140   2
44  2683269923140   2
60  2345620067722   1
```

Comment: please share your DBMS, and even the version.

Comment: _window_ function <> _windows_ function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select ID, TransactionID, Dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by transactionID) 
Rank 
from table1
```

This would give your expected results. Dense rank will not skip ranking and will give the same rank if the ordering column has the same value.

Comment: @sentinel120 you might try to accept the answer, if helped.

Comment: Plus one from me for guessing correctly what sentinel120 wanted.